# Trying to replace original file with created temp file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, temporary-files

I want to do some changes in one file. For this purpose I am doing a temporary file where I write content with all wanted changes and at the end I try to replace the original file with this temp one.

Temp file is created and it looks like I expected, but replacing operation do not work.

This is my code which fails:

```
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w', prefix=basename, dir=dirname, delete=False) as temp, open(file_path, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        temp.write(line + " test")
    os.replace(temp.name, file_path)
```

but this gives me an error:

> PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file
>   because it is being used by another process

Is my usage of 'replace' function is wrong?

Comment: That error seems pretty self explanatory. You need to close the temp file after writing, before replacing.

Comment: Don't use `os.replace`. Use [`shutil.move`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move). `os.replace` only works if the source and destination are on the same device.

Comment: `os.replace` is still contained within `with tempfile(...) as ...`, which means your tempfile is still open. As the error suggests, you cannot change a file while it is still in use. Remove the indent for your last line and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your command os.replace(temp.name, file_path) has to be out of the with.

```
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w', prefix=basename, dir=dirname, delete=False) as temp, open(file_path, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        temp.write(line + " test")
os.replace(temp.name, file_path)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are calling replace() inside 'with' the file is still open as you are still inside the scope of 'with'.

As soon as you're out of 'with' the file has now been closed and you can now replace with os.replace().

Try it.

```
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w', prefix=basename, dir=dirname, delete=False) as temp, open(file_path, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        temp.write(line + " test")
os.replace(temp.name, file_path)
```